# Sectioned ListView with Images in android

Tags: android, listview

i have successfully implemented sectioned listview, but now i want to add image into it. I actually dont know now how to proceed please guide me. Below is the snapshot of the row of listview.
[image]

Here is the code snippet for ListView:

```
adapter.addSection((keys.get(i)), new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), security, R.layout.list_complexblue, new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION, ITEM_DATE, VISIBLE_DATE, LINK, IMAGE }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption, R.id.list_complex_pubDate, R.id.list_visible_pubDate, R.id.list_complex_link, R.id.list_complex_image }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a static image don't specify it in your above declaration just place it in the right position in layout. But if it is dynamic image than you must use a custom adapter that extends simple adapter and than specify image on each iteration for a row.

Thanx